# Rails - Form with radio-buttons with javascript actions to enable/disable elements attached

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I want to create a form where there is a block of three linked radio buttons, each one with a separate input field attached, e.g.

- Option 1: [**__*Dropdown box*__**]
- Option 2: [**__*Dropdown box*__**]
- Option 3: [**__*Text field*__**]

Each of the three options will have an attribute in the model.

I want each of the three options to have a radio button, which when selected will automatically activate the input field beside it, and disable the other two. In the controller when the form is submitted, I also need to know which radio button was selected, take the value from the associated input, and set the other two fields to nil before saving the record.

I tried this a few months ago and failed miserably, giving it another go now still isn't making a lot of sense to me, I'm very inexperienced in any web UI/markup languages.

If anyone could point me to an example or the necessary resources so I can read up on the various methods I need to combine, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this to make it work:

View:

```
<label for="hide" style="display: inline-block">Override V</label>
<input id="v_toggle" type="checkbox" value="Hide" />
<br/>
<%= f.input :v_id, :collection => @vs, :prompt => "Choose a V" %>
<%= f.input :v, :label => false %>
```

JS file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('#service_v').hide();
    jQuery('#v_toggle').live('click', function(event) {        
        jQuery('#service_v_id').toggle('show');
        jQuery('#service_v').toggle('show');            
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-radio_button

Pass a value to :class to group the radio buttons. assign different id to each radio button and in javascript handle the hide/show of related fields. In model, use validations depending upon the value passed by selected radio button.

```
validates :mmc_value, :numericality => { :message => ERR_NUMBER }, :if => :modifier_type

def modifier_type
  ['MMC', 'LMC'].include?(self.modifier) #modifier is the value on which the validation of other fields is based.
end
```